# Definite integral of Dirac delta with trigonometric argument

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, distribution-theory, substitution, dirac-delta

I've been doing some homework with Dirac delta, and while evaluating a given integral, I noticed an 'error' in my approach that I can't quite figure out.

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta ~ \delta(\sin\theta) ~d\theta.$$

I figured a potentially easy solution would involve identity $$cos^2\theta=1-sin^2\theta$$
Thus, expanding the integral

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1-sin^2\theta) \cdot \delta(sin\theta) d\theta$$

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\delta(sin\theta) d\theta -\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} sin^2\theta \cdot\delta(sin\theta) d\theta$$

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\delta(sin\theta) d\theta -\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} sin\theta \cdot sin\theta \cdot\delta(sin\theta) d\theta$$

Now I assumed since,

$$x \delta(x) = 0$$

That

$$sin\theta\delta(sin\theta) = 0$$

as well, which would lead to

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\delta(sin\theta) d\theta - 0$$
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\delta(sin\theta)d\theta = 1$$

However, I believe the initial integral is supposed to evaluate to zero (at least according to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Bcos%2C2%5D%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%CE%B4%5C%2840%29sinx%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C-Divide%5B%CF%80%2C2%5D%2CDivide%5B%CF%80%2C2%5D%7D%5D)

So I deduced

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos^2\theta \cdot \delta(sin\theta) d\theta \neq \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1-sin^2\theta) \cdot \delta(sin\theta) d\theta$$

However, I can't quite understand why.

I'm relatively new to dirac-delta integrations, so if anyone would be able to explain as to why we can't utilize the identity and expand, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1 is the correct answer, your brackets are messed up in your Mathematica query

Comment: iTo see how Mathematica interprets $(\cos)^2(x)$. look at..https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%29cos%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29

Comment: $\displaystyle\delta\left(\sin\left(\theta\right)\right) =
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\,\,\,{\delta\left(\theta - n\pi\right) \over \left\vert\cos\left(n\pi\right)\right\vert} =
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(\theta - n\pi\right).\qquad$
So, you'll get
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)\delta\left(\theta\right)\,{\rm d}\theta = {\LARGE \pi}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A simpler method is [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution):

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\! \mathrm{d}\theta~ \cos^2\theta~\delta(\sin\theta)~\stackrel{s=\sin\theta}{=}~\int_{-1}^1\! \mathrm{d}s~ \sqrt{1-s^2}~\delta(s)~=~1. $$